# How can I list all users on my front end page after logging in as admin?

Tags: strapi

I am a Strapi beginner and have a simple question:

How can I list all users on my front end page after logging in as the admin?
Is there an apiUrl for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you calling /auth/local api to login the response returns a jwt token. Use that token to call /users api.

You can find the detailed information at https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/guides/authentication.html#registration.

Comment: Not useful, page is not there anymore.